# Literal vs variable in T-SQL query with view produces vastly different query time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan, sql-view

When I use a literal in a WHERE clause in a query against a view, the result is basically instantaneous. When I use a variable set to that same value, a completely different and very slow query plan takes its place. How is this possible? How can these be vastly different:

```
DECLARE @a INT = 5

SELECT ... 
WHERE myview.mycol = @a
```

vs

```
SELECT ... 
WHERE myview.mycol = 5
```

Here is the exact query and timing that I am encountering (I can post additional information about the view itself, but I don't know that posting the view definition itself is that useful: it is complex and relies on a dozen other views and tables. I can post it if it's helpful in answering the question.)

```
DECLARE @productdbuid INT = 5

DECLARE @t1 DATETIME;
DECLARE @t2 DATETIME;

---------------------
SET @t1 = GETDATE();

SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  vwPublishingActions 
WHERE 
  productdbuid = 5 AND storedbuid = 1

SET @t2 = GETDATE();
SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@t1,@t2) time1;

---------------------
SET @t1 = GETDATE();

SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  vwPublishingActions 
WHERE 
  productdbuid = @productdbuid AND storedbuid = 1

SET @t2 = GETDATE();
SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@t1,@t2) time2;
```

- time1: 13
- time2: 2796

What is causing SQL Server to treat the literal 5 so differently from `@productbuid INT = 5`?

Thanks so much for any guidance.

**UPDATE**: I've been asked to include the view definition:

```
SELECT
    T2.productdbuid, 
    T2.storedbuid, 
    ISNULL(paca.publishactiondbuid, 8) publishingaction,  -- 8 = ERROR_REPORT
    T2.change_product,
    T2.change_price,
    T2.change_stockstatus,
    T2.inventory_belowtrigger,
    T2.ruledbuid ruledbuid
FROM
    (SELECT
         T.productdbuid, 
         T.storedbuid, 
         -- pick first fully matching set of conditions
         (SELECT TOP 1 paca.dbuid
          FROM dbo.z_PublishingActionCalcs paca
          WHERE (paca.storetypedbuid = T.storetypedbuid) 
            AND (paca.publishingcommanddbuid = T.publishcommanddbuid OR paca.publishingcommanddbuid IS NULL) 
            AND (ISNULL(paca.publishingstatusdbuid, 0) = ISNULL(T.publishstatusdbuid, 1007) OR paca.publishingstatusdbuid IS NULL)  -- 1007 = NOTSET
            AND (ISNULL(ABS(paca.change_product),0) = ISNULL(ABS(T.change_product),0) OR paca.change_product IS NULL) 
            AND (ISNULL(ABS(paca.change_price),0) = ISNULL(ABS(T.change_price),0) OR paca.change_price IS NULL) 
            AND (ISNULL(ABS(paca.change_stockstatus),0) = ISNULL(ABS(T.change_stockstatus),0) OR paca.change_stockstatus IS NULL) 
            AND (ISNULL(ABS(paca.inventory_belowtrigger),0) = ISNULL(ABS(T.inventory_belowtrigger),0) OR paca.inventory_belowtrigger IS NULL)
            AND (ISNULL(paca.stockstatusdbuid, 0) = ISNULL(T.stockstatusdbuid, 0) OR paca.stockstatusdbuid IS NULL) 
      ORDER BY paca.sort) ruledbuid,
      ABS(ISNULL(T.change_product,0)) change_product,
      ABS(ISNULL(T.change_price,0)) change_price,
      ABS(ISNULL(T.change_stockstatus,0)) change_stockstatus,
      ABS(ISNULL(T.inventory_belowtrigger,0)) inventory_belowtrigger
  FROM            
      (SELECT
           p.productid, 
           s.storetypedbuid, 
           CASE 
              WHEN pdpcm.publishcommanddbuid <> 4 
                 THEN NULL  -- STOCKSTATUS
                 ELSE pss.stockstatusdbuid
           END product_stockstatus, 
           CASE 
              WHEN pdpcm.publishcommanddbuid <> 5 
                 THEN NULL  -- INVENTORY
                 ELSE itr.inventory_belowtrigger
           END inventory_belowtrigger, 
           p.dbuid productdbuid, 
           s.dbuid storedbuid, 
           pdpc.change_product, 
           pdpc.change_price, 
           pdpc.change_stockstatus, 
           pdpcm.publishcommanddbuid,
           pdps.publishstatusdbuid,
           pss.stockstatusdbuid
       FROM
           dbo.ProductDetailsPublishingCommands pdpcm
       INNER JOIN 
           dbo.Stores s ON s.dbuid = pdpcm.storedbuid 
       INNER JOIN 
           dbo.Products p ON pdpcm.productdbuid = p.dbuid 
       INNER JOIN 
           dbo.StoreTypeSet st ON st.dbuid = s.storetypedbuid 
       LEFT JOIN 
           dbo.vwPublishingChanges pdpc ON pdpc.productdbuid = p.dbuid 
                                        AND pdpc.storedbuid = s.dbuid
       LEFT JOIN 
           dbo.ProductDetailsPublishingStatuses pdps ON pdps.productdbuid = p.dbuid 
                                                     AND pdps.storedbuid = s.dbuid
       LEFT JOIN 
           dbo.vwProductStockStatus pss ON pss.productdbuid = p.dbuid
       LEFT JOIN 
           dbo.vwProductInventory pri ON pri.productdbuid = p.dbuid
       LEFT JOIN 
           dbo.vwInventoryTriggers itr ON itr.storedbuid = s.dbuid 
                                       AND itr.productdbuid = p.dbuid) T
    ) T2
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.z_PublishingActionCalcs paca ON T2.ruledbuid = paca.dbuid
```

Comment: What is the definition of vwPublishingActions? What do the execution plans look like?

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks, I've posted the view definition now. I will try to post some info on the difference between the execution plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to look at the execution plan to be sure.

When you use a variable `mycol = @a` SQL Server will create a plan based on average column density for values in `mycol`.

The `mycol = 5` predicate may be significantly above or below the average. When you use a literal SQL Server can lookup the value `5` in the column statistics and potentially get more accurate estimates and thus a more appropriate plan.

Additionally using a literal can allow some additional optimisations and simplifications.

An example is that a view with a `PARTITION BY mycol` can have the literal predicate [pushed further down](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views) than a variable or parameter generally can (except when using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`).

Additionally with the literal value available at compilation SQL Server may be able to simplify expressions and use contradiction detection to eliminate some of the work at run time.

Comment: Martin thanks. I still don't understand the difference - I'm not passing in a variable value to a function, it's a variable declared and set right in the query. Surely SQL Server knows that my variable has a value that can be used just as easily as the literal it represents?

Comment: @SalahatSoapHope - SQL Server does not "sniff" the value of variables except if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` - the batch is compiled before the variable is even assigned but it won't sniff them even if the statement is recompiled after the assignment except with that hint. This is because the assignment to local variables is/was a common technique to get around parameter sniffing issues and this technique would be broken if it started sniffing variables routinely.